# How to make dynamic connecting textures

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make a texture for connected stone slabs (no, not the double stone slabs that would be seamless). I'm talking placing two slabs next to each other, and the light gray being carried across, and only using the dark gray as a border, similar to the way logs do.

My question is: how can I  do this? I know it has to do with a file in the texture pack, but have no idea what file it is, or how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have used resource packs, and I don't believe you can do this. You'd have to change how the textures work for slabs, in which would be rather difficult.

Comment: @TheMattbat999 I'm fairly certain it can be done, because blocks like connected glass, wood, and others do exist.

Comment: @David It can be done, except it requires modifying the game code. The code is built in a certain way that certain blocks will join together with a certain formality. Regardless of the textures, the code itself needs to be modified for the textures to connect the way you want them to.

Comment: @finnrayment CTC/Optifine already provides the template for modification

Comment: @David Oh, sorry. I haven't used it in that long I was ignorant to believe it was as it has been for a long time. Pardon me! :)

Comment: @finnrayment No problemo :p I myself doubted that someone like me could begin to understand how to do it, but over the years Optifine has made it very basic to do

Comment: @David Haha yes. First with replacements for side-blocks, and now this! Maybe I should get back into Minecraft again.... :3

Comment: And so much more with Microsoft now owning Minecraft. Heard they're bringing it to 4K ;3 @finnrayment

Comment: @David Oh wow! Quick question, is it even Java anymore or did they migrate it completely/planning on moving it over to C++ like they have with the Windows 10 edition?

Comment: I hope they migrate to C++... As of 1.12 for PC, Java is still the only supported version across all OS-es @finnrayment

Comment: @David As a programmer of both (or though I'm useless in C++) It's a shame to see them leave Java, it's much easier to deal with cross-platform natives rather than dealing with multi-os binaries. Still, atleast it will run better ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62288/discussion-between-david-and-finnrayment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a job for <strike>Superman</strike> Connected Textures Mod (CTM), which is included in OptiFine. If you haven't already, go ahead and download the latest version of OptiFine before you continue reading this.

In order for this mod to work, you'll have to create three `.properties` files; one for the side texture, another one for the top texture and one for the bottom texture. The names of the files doesn't really matter, but it's good to know what the different files are used for.

***Edited for 1.15.2***:

**smooth_stone_slab_side.properties**

> matchBlocks=smooth_stone_slab smooth_stone
>   method=horizontal
>   tiles=100-103
>   connect=block
>   faces=sides

**smooth_stone_slab_top.properties**

> matchBlocks=smooth_stone_slab smooth_stone
>   method=ctm_compact
>   tiles=104-108
>   faces=top

**smooth_stone_slab_bottom.properties**

> matchBlocks=smooth_stone_slab smooth_stone
>   method=ctm_compact
>   tiles=104-108
>   faces=bottom

After that we need to add textures for the connecting slabs but since I don't know how many images I can add to this answer, I've decided to merge all textures as one image so you'll have to split them up in nine 16×16px PNG images yourself. Make sure to name them according to the table below in order to make everything work out.

> 100.png | 101.png | 102.png
>
> 103.png | 104.png | 105.png
>
> 106.png | 107.png | 108.png

[image: Sprite of all stone slab textures]

Now we have to create a resource pack and add some folders where all these files and images should be. In the resource pack, open the `assets` and `minecraft` folders, then you have to create a new folder called `optifine`. Inside this new folder, create another folder named `ctm`. And inside this folder, you must create *yet another* folder which you name `default`.

Add the `.properties` files and images to the `default` folder. If done correctly, you should have this folder structure:

> | assets/
>   | - minecraft/
>   | --  optifine/
>   | ---   ctm/
>   | ----    default/

When you start Minecraft, go to `Options -> Video Settings -> Quality` and set `Connected Textures` to either `Fast` or `Fancy` and apply your newly created resource pack. When you are done, it should look like this:

[image: Image depicting the wonders of CTM]

Have fun!

Edit: Added a `.properties` file for the bottom texture of the slabs.
<s>Edit 2: Added the `metadata` parameter for the files so the texture is only applied to top and bottom stone slabs.</s>

Comment: All of my slabs are now a pale white - [link](http://imgur.com/a/tVkb4) - what went wrong?

Comment: @David I've been trying to reproduce your result without any success - it looks good on my end. I see that you are using Faithful, so I've created textures for Faithful [here](http://imgur.com/Gbcqt9B). Can you replace your images and try it out to check if there is any difference? Also, I noticed that I missed to add a file to provide a connected bottom texture for the slabs.

Comment: Would any of this be changed by me using 1.10.2?

Comment: @David Maybe, maybe not. Can you use 1.12 to check if it works?

Comment: Same thing is happening in 1.12...

Comment: I feel like I'm doing something wrong.. could you upload the resourcepack for download?

Comment: @David Here you go! https://ufile.io/9t2sn

Comment: New issue.. since 44 is universally the Id for slabs, all slabs now look likes stone slabs... O-o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62300/discussion-between-david-and-spitz).

Comment: @David Long time no see! I fixed the texture pack and posted a link to it in the chat room you linked back in July, but since the link is dead now and I never received any reply from you, I figured you never tested it. [https://ufile.io/5lass](Here's a link to the texture pack.)

Comment: Well, crappo! My internet went out back in July, and when I came back to the world, I forgot to tell ya, it worked. Sorry for the delay :)

Comment: @David Aw, that's too bad. Don't worry about it, I'm glad to hear it worked out. :-D

Comment: Crappo! Link expired again, and after having to wipe my drive, I don't have it.. Think you could send me another link? (I promise this will be the last time)

Comment: @David No worries, here you go: https://ufile.io/3dk8m

Comment: Hey Spitz, know it's been a heck of a long time, I was wondering if you still had the file?

Comment: @David Haha. I knew this would happen again. Luckily I had the file in my Recycle bin, so here you go: https://ufile.io/jmwwe You really need to store this on Google Drive/OneDrive/whatever cloud service you are using so you don't lose it.

Comment: Gonna go upload it now :P sorry I had it stored on a harddrive, but the drive was corrupted

Comment: BUMP! Broken again in 1.14.

Comment: @David Try renaming `stone_slab‌` to `smooth_stone_slab‌`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was the first thing I tried, and it no longer works. I may open a new question on this topic as this one seems to be over-saturated with outdated answers as of 1.14

Answer (score 2):

matchblocks was changed somewhat recently in optifine -- instead of `matchBlocks=44` it should be `matchBlocks=stone_slab` or alternatively `minecraft:stone_slab` see this demo file for details https://github.com/sp614x/optifine/blob/master/OptiFineDoc/doc/ctm.properties

Comment: You are talking about [The Flattening](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/1.13/Flattening), which happened in 1.13 and affected vanilla Minecraft, not only OptiFine.

Comment: You’re right, I’m sorry to have forgotten the 1.13 caveat — however, the flattening also seems like affects optifine — or maybe block ids still works as well? Pretty sure I’ve seen people complains that they had to change to block names for optifine CTM as well

Comment: No need to apologize. As far as I know, numerical block ids doesn't work at all in OptiFine 1.13+, since I had to change all `.properties` files for my CTM resource pack.
Speaking of changes, `minecraft:stone_slab` will be renamed to `smooth_stone_slab‌` in 1.14.