# CTM Not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-optifine, minecraft-resource-packs

Following a previous (admittedly old) [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/313074/how-to-make-dynamic-connecting-textures)'s answer, I remade a [connected textures pack](http://www.mediafire.com/file/a9ncz60z964o2oh/Connected_Slabs_-_oBlazin.rar/file) for stone slabs, after my hard drive was wiped.

The issue arising is that only the bottom and top of the slabs will now connect.

[image]

This seems odd to me. The files have been setup 100% the same as the answer instructed, and this used to work. I am using Optifine 1.12.2 D3, which has CTM built in, on forge 1.12.2-14.23.4.2379.

Comment: I never understood what "connected textures" does. To me, this just looks like regular stone slabs.

Comment: @FabianRöling [Here](https://imgur.com/a/T544rQI) is a picture of the un-altered stone slabs. Notice the lines between slabs laid horizontally. Connected textures removes that.

Comment: Oh, I thought the two in front were one and this was some weird FOV thing. Minecraft uses wide FOVs incorrectly, so this might as well be somehow a possible screenshot with one slab.

Comment: Can you upload the resource pack and link it here?

Comment: [The resource pack](http://www.mediafire.com/file/a9ncz60z964o2oh/Connected_Slabs_-_oBlazin.rar/file)

Comment: On that picture they can't connect, because they're double slabs.. or did you adjust those as well?

Comment: @dly Is there a different way to connect double slabs?

Comment: Different ID at least. You can just try to connect one layer of slabs without turning them into double slabs and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Any additions and changes are **bold**.

stoneslab_bottom.properties:

> matchBlocks=**43-**44
>   method=ctm_compact
>   tiles=104-108
>   **connect=tile**
>   faces=bottom
>   metadata=0 8

stoneslab_side.properties:

> matchBlocks=**43-**44
>   method=horizontal
>   tiles=100-103
>   connect=**tile**
>   faces=sides
>   metadata=0 8

stoneslab_top.properties:

> matchBlocks=**43-**44
>   method=ctm_compact
>   tiles=104-108
>   **connect=tile**
>   faces=top
>   metadata=0 8