# CTM Packs In 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-optifine

As of 1.12; [this resource pack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/337388/ctm-not-working) would connect stone slabs as expected (after the question linked was answered). In 1.13, however, the pack no longer does this, and I was wondering why. Has CTM changed in 1.13 to require new parameters, or does it no longer function the way I was expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that needs to be changed in order for a resource pack with OptiFine functionality to work in 1.13. If you are still going to play in 1.12, I recommend that you create a backup of your resource pack so you don't have to make these adjustments every time you switch versions.

## [Folder merge](https://github.com/sp614x/optifine/issues/1557)

The `mcpatcher` folder is no longer used in 1.13 and all of its contents should be moved to the `optifine` folder. If you don't have a `optifine` folder in your resource pack, just rename the `mcpatcher` folder to "optifine".

Wrong:

> \assets\minecraft\mcpatcher\ctm\

Correct:

> \assets\minecraft\optifine\ctm\

## [The Flattening](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Flattening)

Item/block IDs are no longer numerical and must use the new IDs that were introduced in 1.13. ***Note that `stone_slab‌` will be renamed to `smooth_stone_slab‌` in 1.14.***

Any additions and changes are **bold**.

stoneslab_bottom.properties:

> matchBlocks=**stone_slab**
> method=ctm_compact
> tiles=104-108
> connect=tile
> faces=bottom
> <strike>metadata=0 8</strike>

stoneslab_side.properties:

> matchBlocks=**stone_slab**
> method=horizontal
> tiles=100-103
> connect=tile
> faces=sides
> <strike>metadata=0 8</strike>

stoneslab_top.properties:

> matchBlocks=**stone_slab**
> method=ctm_compact
> tiles=104-108
> connect=tile
> faces=top
> <strike>metadata=0 8</strike>

Comment: You're a savior! I wish I could upvote this answer more than once.